# Image Pyramid + Geoserver + Google Earth slow with errors

Tags: gdal

I have hundreds of GB of somewhat small tif files. Here is gdalinfo of one of them:

```
F:\gis\geotiffs>gdalinfo finaloutputSSAM211Jun181306hfwaterfall0.tif
Driver: GTiff/GeoTIFF
Files: finaloutputSSAM211Jun181306hfwaterfall0.tif
Size is 2281, 4301
Coordinate System is:
GEOGCS["WGS 84",
DATUM["WGS_1984",
    SPHEROID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","7030"]],
    AUTHORITY["EPSG","6326"]],
PRIMEM["Greenwich",0],
UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
AUTHORITY["EPSG","4326"]]
Origin = (-85.749319836621979,30.000952072441574)
Pixel Size = (0.000000303816798,-0.000000303816798)
Metadata:
 AREA_OR_POINT=Area
Image Structure Metadata:
  INTERLEAVE=PIXEL
 Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  ( -85.7493198,  30.0009521) ( 85d44'57.55"W, 30d 0' 3.43"N)
Lower Left  ( -85.7493198,  29.9996454) ( 85d44'57.55"W, 29d59'58.72"N)
Upper Right ( -85.7486268,  30.0009521) ( 85d44'55.06"W, 30d 0' 3.43"N)
Lower Right ( -85.7486268,  29.9996454) ( 85d44'55.06"W, 29d59'58.72"N)
Center      ( -85.7489733,  30.0002987) ( 85d44'56.30"W, 30d 0' 1.08"N)
Band 1 Block=2281x1 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Red
  Mask Flags: PER_DATASET ALPHA
Band 2 Block=2281x1 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Green
  Mask Flags: PER_DATASET ALPHA
Band 3 Block=2281x1 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Blue
  Mask Flags: PER_DATASET ALPHA
Band 4 Block=2281x1 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Alpha
```

I used gdal_retile.py with the following command line:

```
gdal_retile.py -v -r bilinear -levels 4 -ps 2048 2048 -co "tiled=YES" -targetDir pyramid --optfile files.txt
```

I then create an Image Pyramid store in Geoserver and set multithreading to true, and USE_JAI_IMAGEREAD in the layer. When I go to Layer Preview and click on KML it opens in Google Earth. When I zoom in, it takes a very long time to render, and sometimes it times out and gives me various errors.

Currently I built the Image Pyramids with only 30 or 145 of those tifs to see if maybe it was because my data set was so large, however I get the same performance with those smaller sets.

What am I doing wrong?

Here is a picture of one error I am getting:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/wMlOO.jpg

I also get an error that just says "Error when parsing file"

Thanks!

Comment: Actually I think I found my own mistake. I was making 145 image pyramids apparently instead of just one image pyramid. Calling gdal_retile.py multiple times on multiple files creates multiple image pyramids. You need to use the --optfile option to send it a list of files to make only one image pyramid.

Comment: Not only that, gdal_retile.py wont accept filenames with spaces and/or hyphens. It also needs to the tifs to be converted to north-up or it crashes.